# What's the point of the cardboard castles in Kingdomino?

Tags: kingdomino

I cannot find a function for them; what is the point? Just marking each player's starting half-domino?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main point of the castles is to confirm your player colour. You could use your second king meeple to do the same thing, except in a 2-player game where you use both meeples.

Answer (score 4):

Right now, they show your color.

And yes they have no real purpose in the game. But a kingdom needs a castle, so I think it is a nice addition.